# Autocomplete Text view

Tags: database

I am developing apps in which i'm using two autocompletetextview in which first autocompletetextview  data i'm fetching from database and in second autocompletetextview i want only those data which is related to first autocompletetextview.
Means if there is 3 column in database and 1 column is link to first autocomlepettextview then only those data in column 2 has to be visible which is selected in column .
 public String[] getSymptom()
        {
            Cursor cursor = this.sqliteDBInstance.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COLUMN_2_Symptom}, null, null, null, null, null);

```
        if(cursor.getCount() >0)
        {
             str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int i = 0;

            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                 str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_2_Symptom));
                 i++;
             }

            return str;
        }
        else
        {
            return new String[] {};
        }
    }


    public String[] getSymptom1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] clmn=new String[]{COLUMN_3_Symptom1};
        Cursor curs=this.sqliteDBInstance.query(DB_TABLE_NAME,clmn ,"Symptom = ?",new String[]{COLUMN_2_Symptom},null,null,null);
        //Cursor curs=this.sqliteDBInstance.rawQuery("Select Symptom1 from Diseaseslist where Symptom='" + + "'  ", null);
        if(curs.getCount()>0)
        {
            str1 = new String[curs.getCount()];
            int j= 0;
            while(curs.moveToNext())
            {
                str1[j] = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_3_Symptom1));
                j++;
            }
            return str1;
        }
        else
        {
        return new String[] {};
        }
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you advertising your services for building 3-column autocomplete applications? :-)

Comment: I'm not advertising  the question is just for an example if i select a state in first autocompletetext then only those city under that state has to be displayed in second autocompletetextview...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what environment you're building your app under, so I'll assume it's a web app.

What you're asking for is called "cascading auto-complete" - here's an example with code:

http://www.webdeveasy.com/cascading-autocompletes-using-jquery-ui/

Comment: the first method im passing to Autocompletetext1 and second method to Autocompletetext2 and the prob is is its not showing anything in second autocompletetext